# Changing you own answer in Java

Tags: java, random

I am currently working on a program in Java. It's a cardgame where you have to guess the numbers which are randomly generated of three cards (4, 5 or 6). If you guessed the numbers in the right order, you win. If you do not guess these numbers in the right order the first time, you may retry only one card. So far all of this I got to work, however when I want to change my second or the third answer I have to type '2' two times or '3' three times to change these cards. Here is my code:

```
package cardgame;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CardGame {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] guess = new int[3];
    int[] card = new int[3];

    System.out.println("Pick three cards with numbers ranging from 4 to 6!\n");

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
       System.out.print("Card number " + (i+1) + " (4, 5 or 6): ");
       guess[i] = scan.nextInt();
       }
       System.out.println(" ");
       System.out.println("Your hand of cards: " + "[" + guess[0] + "]" + "[" + guess[1] + "]" + "[" + guess[2] + "]");

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
       card[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 2 +2);
       }

       int count = 0;
       for (int i=0; i<3; i++){
    if (card[i] == guess[i])
       count++;
          }

    if (count == 3){
       System.out.println("My hand of cards: " + "[" + card[0] + "]" + "[" + card[1] + "]" + "[" + card[2] + "]\n");
       System.out.println("Congratulations, you have won!\nType 'end' to end the game and I will show you my hand of cards.");
       } else{
       System.out.println("Not quite yet there!\n");
       }

    if (count !=3){
       System.out.println("Would you like to change one of your guesses? yes/no");
       }

    if("yes".equals(scan.next())){
       System.out.println("\nWhat card would you like to change? 1/2/3");
       {

    if(scan.nextInt() == 1 || scan.nextInt() == 2 || scan.nextInt() == 3){
       System.out.println("\nWhat is your new guess?");
       int secondGuess = scan.nextInt();

    if (secondGuess == card[0] || secondGuess == card[1] || secondGuess == card[2]){
        count++;  
       }

    if (count == 3){
       System.out.println("\nCongratulations, you have won!");
       } else{
       System.out.println("\nI'm sorry, you lost!");
       }
     }
   }      
 }
       // Print the 3 random numbers card[0], card[1] and card[2]
       System.out.println("My hand of cards: " + "[" + card[0] + "]" + "[" + card[1] + "]" + "[" + card[2] + "]\n");
    }
  }
```

Output so far:

```
Pick three cards with numbers ranging from 4 to 6!

Card number 1 (4, 5 or 6): 4

Card number 2 (4, 5 or 6): 5

Card number 3 (4, 5 or 6): 6

Your hand of cards: [4][5][6]

Not quite yet there!

Would you like to change one of your guesses? yes/no

yes

What card would you like to change? 1/2/3

2

2

What is your new guess?

6

Congratulations, you have won!

My hand of cards: [4][4][6]
```

As you can see, I have to insert two twice. Also my new guess was 6 on the second spot and to win it should have been 4 on the second spot. Where have I gone wrong? I can't seem to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `scan.nextInt` up to 3 times in this line:

```
if(scan.nextInt() == 1 || scan.nextInt() == 2 || scan.nextInt() == 3){
```

which will read up to three numbers depending on what numbers you type in.

- First number is 1: only one number read.
- First number isn't 1 and second number is 2: two numbers read.
- Else, 3 numbers read.

Grab the number once, then compare it:

```
int someNumber = scan.nextInt();
if(someNumber  == 1 || someNumber  == 2 || someNumber  == 3){
```

Comment: Oh, such a stupid mistake! Thank you for pointing out. Works like a charm now.